# How to determine if a matrix is a subspace of M_2x2 and provide its basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

This is a question from my linear algebra homework that I don't really understand, so I'm not completely sure how to ask a good question about it.

> Let  $$ \{A \subset \mathcal{M}\ _{2x2} :
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>     1\\
>     2
>   \end{bmatrix} \subset \mathbf{N} (A) \}
>  $$ Determine if $A$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{M}\ _{2x2}$ and, if it is, find a basis.

I'm not really sure where to start at all, so any hints about how to think about it and get started would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Write $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}& a_{22}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, $$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\in N(A)\iff \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}& a_{22}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

So, $$a_{11}+2a_{12}=a_{21}+2a_{22}=0.$$ That is

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-2a_{12}&a_{12}\\-2a_{22}& a_{22}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Can you find now a basis?

Comment: How do I determine if it is a subspace of M_{2x2}?

Comment: Let's call by W the set. Is the zero matrix in W? Is the sum of two matrices in W an element of W? Is it the product of a scalar and a matrix in W still in W?